# Accumulating a Map from an Array In TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of TypeScript objects with shape that is essentially the following:

```
interface MyObject {
  id: string
  position: number
}
```

I am trying to convert this array into a map of id to position that looks like this for a JSON POST down the line:

```
{ 
   "id1": 1,
   "id2": 2,
}
```

One approach is to use an ES6 `Map`:

`array.reduce((map, obj) => map.set(obj.id, obj.position), new Map())`

That works, but converting an ES6 `Map` to JSON is problematic.

I have tried to accumulate the key-value pairs into a pure object literal, but TypeScript has been hating everything I try, which includes [Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types), `Object.create({})`, and a lot of other ideas.

How can I distill a pure object literal of key value pairs from an array of objects?

Comment: I think writing the numbers as strings might solve your problem, e.g `1` --> `"1"`.

Comment: `Object.create(null)` would be the right `Map` equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your target environment supports ES2019, you could use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), like this:

```
function arrToObjES2019(arr: MyObject[]) {
  return Object.fromEntries(arr.map(({ id, position }) => [id, position]));
}
```

Or, if not, you can make your own polyfill-like version of `Object.fromEntries()` using array `reduce()` on an empty object, like this:

```
function fromEntries<V>(iterable: Iterable<[string, V]>) {
  return [...iterable].reduce((obj, [key, val]) => {
    obj[key] = val
    return obj
  }, {} as {[k: string]: V})
}
```

and then use it:

```
function arrToObj(arr: MyObject[]) {
  return fromEntries(arr.map(({ id, position }) => [id, position]));
}
```

Either way should let you do what you want:

```
const arr: MyObject[] = [
  { id: "id1", position: 1 },
  { id: "id2", position: 2 }
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrToObj(arr))); // {"id1":1,"id2":2}
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEFEGUCYAYEYCcoAmBTAZgSwHZYC5YD2OAzgFC75oBOGAhgMZqgDyARgFZqP4DCJUvhoBXXkRqgA3uVBzQGGkQC24HMKxpSAHgAqoALyh6OAJ4A+ABRp1NTaQBcoAJLUa9dgBs02mmnooJJ6moADaAApKAA60+KYA0mimADSgugC65gCUTlJhANaguKCRRDE0cYmm6U76AL4A3LLyiipqGlrWtvZOrrQe3r7+gTjBxmahmTnjpk115JTqtAzMoACyphzcvNLNWChOQnY4AOZNclFEpATEOE44IsrstHMLGCI4vLfGNDS6RFsoHAkJZ6L8nBstjx8JMsrs5H58CIaDg2FxoQA6VqqbqdME0DHKehRSyWPL7VKXa6EEigOpwgzmMIU0BUm4kdJZLKvcjvT401HY9p2LTaABqVgI-S8aF6bgGPlCR1wJ1SYqm8NAiORqNCGP1UvcMvSGL8KDEaFJRC4qVC+SSqQAbvRPJzDEyZPJQNbOHakulDKBnZ5mgi0EiUd6uM06qkpHVjKRpHbDhpTjVQGL6eR5ryPl9afj-ltQeD1pt0bxYZrtZGhbjSKWCUSSWSiihKVd2aj6e7mR3WV2BZzuTmFuRGIJ8D8aBCK9sYQGjKFmuSDqAAET7eAbzvU25OeB05Kr9tOLcoaC7wf7khOaB08jpJoTwREbwYzxEE6WABSkFYAA5DFlVOLAMFMJtiy4JsuW5UAQGkC8dwceBkgvK8HGgeYgA)

Comment: Thanks for showing me `fromEntries.` As a side note FWIW, since I want to type the JSON request, the type produced from @jcalz's solution is `[index: string]: number` in case you were curious. So I feel a bit better that Indexable Types had some minor relevance to the solution.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why reduce wouldn't be the approach here...

```
array.reduce((acc, val) => 
   Object.assign(acc, {[val.id]: val.position}), {});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do this, it is the simplest way:

```
let newMap = new Map(array.map(obj => [obj.id, obj.position]));
```

Comment: beware: `JSON.stringify` might not work against that `Map` type, and just ignore / not stringify it